# POSTMAN : Convert HTML response to JSON

Tags: python, html, json, django

I am running a Website using Python and Django . 
Here is my `views .py` :

```
def user_login(request):
    user=0
    inactive=0
    if request.method=='POST':
        username=request.POST.get('username')
        print(username)
        password=request.POST.get('password')
        print(password)
        user=authenticate(username=username,password=password)
        if user:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request,user)
                profile=Profile.objects.get(user=user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('accounts:index_with_pk',kwargs={'pk':profile.pk}))
            else:
                inactive = 1
                return render(request, 'accounts/login.html', {'user': user, 'inactive':inactive})
        else:
            print("Some one tried to login and failed")
            print("They typed : UserName {} and Password {}".format(username,password))
            user=1
            return render(request, 'accounts/login.html', {'user': user, 'inactive': inactive})
    else:
        return render(request,'accounts/login.html',{'user':user, 'inactive': inactive})
```

When i run this in POSTMAN ,  i am getting the response in HTML but I want to get the response in JSON . 
In POST method , i requested this url : http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login . The response in HTML , not in JSON.

Comment: In the `Body` part, there is one drop-down button which should show "JSON", "XML", "HTML", "Text", "Auto", Change there and on the left side, click "Pretty".

Comment: In place of `render` you can use `jsonresponse` [https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects]

Comment: Ensure the correct Content-Type header is included in the Postman request. This is likely “application/json” and is not included by default. Otherwise the server may return an unexpected ‘content type’ result based on other configuration factors. Some may also be based on  Accept..

Comment: Your response is HTML because that's what you told django to return. If you want a JSON response, make your view return a JsonResponse containing JSON content. There's no way to automagically turn arbitrary HTML into json, you'll have to do it by yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `JsonResponse` instead of `render` function
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects

Answer (score 0):

set key-value in postman headers and then try.

Content-Type : application/json

Comment: This won't automagically convert the response's content to json you know ?